# Does my computer support OpenGL 2.1?

Tags: linux, opengl, ubuntu

[image]

Basing from the above image, is the max version of Opengl my computer can support is 1.4? does that mean that there's no way I can write code with Opengl 2.1?

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: `sudo apt-get install opengl-2.0-dev`?

Comment: uhm..what I've read opengl support is based on the video card, is that right? I'm on a laptop so I'm using the built-in video card. So, my laptop doesn't support opengl 2.1?

Comment: @markuz: You're looking only at the GLX module version, not the OpenGL version. GLX is the protocol used to create OpenGL contexts on a X11 server. And while it is intimately connected to OpenGL it is not a part of OpenGL. Also GLX-1.4 is a rather modern and new version of GLX.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you see there is the GLX version. GLX is the container protocol, that delivers OpenGL to the X11 server. You should look for the OpenGL version string, which comes a bit later in that output. Use grep to filter the output, e.g. on my laptop

```
datenwolf@narfi ~ 
%> glxinfo | grep version
server glx version string: 1.4
client glx version string: 1.4
GLX version: 1.4
OpenGL version string: 2.1 Mesa 8.0.3
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.20
```

As you can see, my GLX version is 1.4 as well, but I have OpenGL 2.1 and GLSL 1.20 support on my mobile machine.